# Как работает метод acquire в Mutex Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Есть вопросы к логике работы Mutex Yii2;
Допустим, есть Mutex:

```
$mutex = new FileMutex();
$mutexName = 'order-mutex';
$unlockSeconds = 5;

if ($mutex->acquire($mutexName, $unlockSeconds)) {
  // код
  $mutex->release($mutexName);
} else {
  throw new \Exception('');
}
```

**Вопросы:**

1) Что значит второй параметр $timeout в методе acquire($name, $timeout = 0)? Это выставление таймаута, прежде чем будет обрабатываться следующий запрос?

> $timeout time (in seconds) to wait for lock to be released. Defaults to zero meaning that method will return false immediately in case lock was already acquired.[Из PHPDoc]

2) При каких условиях метод acquire() возвращает false, из-за чего выходит бросается исключение?
С этим связана основная проблема: при обращении к API, некоторые клиенты получают данное исключение, вместо постановки(так ли?) запроса в очередь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$timeout` - это время, которое будет ждать второй процесс, пока первый, который захватил блокировку `acquire()`, не отпустит её `release()`.
2. `false` возвращается из `acquire()` во втором процессе после ожидания `$timeout`, если к этому моменту первый процесс не освободил блокировку.